# Searching for multiple labels Gmail API - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail-api

I am using this gem in my rails app to interact with the Gmail API: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

I am able to search for emails containing one label:

```
require 'gmail'
gmail = Gmail.connect("email@gmail.com", "testpwd")
gmail.mailbox('Urgent')
```

But when I try to search for multiple labels, I get an error. How do I find all email that contain two specific labels, such as email that contain both the label "Urgent" and "Priority"?

Comment: This is purely a stab in the dark, but have you tried passing an array to the mailbox method? `gmail.mailbox ['Urgent','Priority']`

Comment: Thank you! I get this error: `localize': undefined method `to_sym' for ['Urgent','Priority']:Array (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using intersection...

```
urgent_priority_emails = gmail.mailbox('Urgent').emails & gmail.mailbox('Priority').emails
```

However, I have a recollection that this may not work, because the emails are treated as different objects even though they are the same messages.

An alternative that may work...

```
   urgent_email_message_ids = gmail.mailbox('Urgent').emails.map{|email|email.message_id}
   urgent_priority_emails = gmail.mailbox('Priority').emails.select{|email| urgent_email_message_ids.include?(email.message_id)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I get this error: undefined method `&' for #<Gmail::Mailbox0x7f98231d0110 name=Urgent> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Hi, yes, so sorry!  Forgot to add the #emails method to get the array of emails from the mailbox.

Comment: I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The gmail gem let's you use the Google search filter, like this:

```
gmail.mailbox('Urgent').emails(gm: 'label:'Priority')
```